# Coding The Relationship Between Prices and Budgets

Tags: regression, econometrics

For models of a binary purchase decision, is there any academic literature or practical wisdom on coding the relationship between item price and a consumer's stated budget?

Consumers will sometimes purchase items that exceed their budgets, or they can be less likely to buy items that are too cheap or too dear relative to their budgets. I can think of several ways of doing this to construct a covariate:

1. an indicator for price $\le$ budget
2. an indicator for price being nearest to the budget in dollars
3. an indicator for price being within x% above budget
4. the difference between price and budget
5. a function of the difference between price and budget that treats being over differently than being under
6. flexible function of the difference between price and budget that is estimated from the data

There are probably others that I did not think of.

I feel like I am reinventing the wheel and that a literature on this should exist in economics, marketing, or psychology. I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: How about a percentage "change" $\frac{\text{price}-\text{budget}}{\text{budget}}$?